# Stackoverflow like modal popup in jquery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Which jquery modal plugin does stackoverflow uses (ie) When i try to close a question? Any suggestion..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SO doesn't use a plugin, it's built just for SO, they just create a `<div>` and stick it in the page, with the following styling:

```
.popup {
  background-color:#fff;
  border:solid 10px #AE0000;
  -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #000;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #000;
  z-index:1;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  padding:15px;
}
```

They just insert the created `<div class="popup">` wherever it goes in the page, in this case it's appended to the parent of the clicked `closed-question-nnnnnn` link (the `.post-menu` div).

Aside from the internals, which would undoubtedly be different anyway, this is all you need to make a modal, [you can view a quick demonstration here](http://jsfiddle.net/r7V5x/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a few model pop-up plug-ins few plugins for jQuery. The one is now part of jQuery UI is [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: The question was which plugin does SO use...it doesn't use one, and it isn't the jQuery UI dialog, which is a *lot* heavier :)

Comment: I understand the question, I'm just suggesting alternates, that may be useful for Murali.